# p4 for vs code always pop up ERROR: Command Failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, perforce, perforce-client-spec

Recently I work on linux, and try to use vs code as dev IDE, every thing is fine except the p4 plug-in is hard to configure. I set "perforce.command": /home/myname/Downloads/p4v-2015/bin/p4v. but when I try to save an unchecked out file, output window tells me:

```
ERROR:
Command failed: "/home/frank/Downloads/p4v-2015/bin/p4v" info
"/home/frank/Downloads/p4v-2015/bin/p4v" opened "/home/frank/Perforce/my_Workspace/<path to the file>/<file>.cpp"
"/home/frank/Downloads/p4v-2015/bin/p4v" opened "/root/.config/Code - Insiders/User/settings.json"
"/home/frank/Downloads/p4v-2015/bin/p4v" login -s
```

can anyone helps me, I have to manually check out files now, it really sucks....

Comment: Probably "perforce command" should be set to a **different** executable, not **p4v** itself.  Where did you find this configuration setting? Is it one of the ones listed here: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4vs/01_aboutp4vs.html

Comment: Given the type of commands that are being executed in your error message, you are probably supposed to set that parameter to the location of your **p4** executable, not your **p4v** executable.

Comment: thanks very helpful

Answer (score 2):

1 download p4 command line executable from https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-command-line-client-p4
2 chmod +x p4(download exe)
3 set env like this:

```
P4PORT="proxy:1666"
P4CLIENT="workspace"
P4PASSWD="0E2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
P4USER="username"
```

PS: run command "p4 login -s" to generate P4PASSWD key.
5 install p4 vs code extension and modify setting like this:

```
perforce.editOnFileSave: true,
perforce.addOnFileCreate: true,
perforce.deleteOnFileDelete: true,
perforce.command: <PATH TO p4>\p4
```

PS: perforce.command has to point to p4 command line exe, NOT p4v.
6 COMPLETE, can auto check out opened file by press "ctrl+s"

Comment: These steps could use some editing for more details... Run 'p4 login -s' from where? P4 root? Stream root?

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan Pendleton mentioned, make sure that you configure your Visual Studio plug-in to use `p4`, *not* `p4v.`

`p4v` is the *graphical* (visual) client; `p4` is the *command-line* client.  The command-line client is the one that you would use for any kind of scripting/automation.